# extract data from Excel on 64-bit machine

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, ado.net

I want to extract all data from an Excel file to a SQL Server 2008 database table. There is 1 to 1 mapping between Excel column and the SQL Server database table column. I am wondering on 64-bit platform (64-bit Windows Server 2008 + 64-bit SQL Server 2008), what technology should I use? Because I am new to this area, appreciate if anyone could provide me some samples or tutorials. I ask this question in the context of 64-bit platform because I heard not all technologies work on both 32-bit and 64-bit.

BTW: I am using VS2008 + .Net 2.0 + C# + Windows Server 2008 x64 + SQL Server 2008 Enterprise 64-bit + ADO.Net + ASP.Net + IIS 7.0.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read data directly from the spreadsheet however it is quicker and simpler to use the SQL Server Management Studio Data Import functionality. Under "Tasks", "Import Data", you have the ability to configure table and column mapping, speciify identity and row override insert rules etc.

Comment: Thanks Lloyd. Your solution works, but I am asking how to do it in a programming way. :-)